# Android Firebase Realtime Database- How to retrieve specific data with different user in different node

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in using Android Studio and Firebase. I am trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude data in the HostID when I using UserID account from Firebase realtime database to search the tracking ID and show the latitude and longitude on the map when the user search with tracking ID.

[image: My database]

[image: Here is my rules for my database]

I have tried to use the query and orderbychild command and the code is as below.

```
 private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();

        Toast.makeText(this, "testing = " + userTrackingID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("ID").equalTo(userTrackingID);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   enterTracking.setError(null);

                   String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                       String lol = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                       Log.i("testing for lol", lol);
                       String value = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", value);
                       


                      String latitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                      String longitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Latitude_Longitude.this, MapsActivity.class);

                      intent.putExtra("latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                      intent.putExtra("longitude", longitudefromDatabase);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   }
               }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                   }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

I keep finding tutorial and and try to apply it to my program. However, I still dont know why and where the coding was wrong as the program cannot shown the message "checking, this is value message" in the logcat when the button is pressed and straight showing the "Invalid Tracking ID from database", which mean the program cannot get the data from database.

Please help me and show me how to correct my coding.

**UPDATES!!!**
I have made some changes to receive the data.

```js
  private void isTrackingID() {
        String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();
        Long userTrackingIDNumber = Long.parseLong(userTrackingID);

        Toast.makeText(this, "testing = " + userTrackingIDNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID");

        Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/ID").equalTo(userTrackingIDNumber);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                  Log.i("checking", "this is value message");

                   //enterTracking.setError(null);

                   //String IDfromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child(userTrackingID).getValue(String.class);

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       String latitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       String longitudefromDatabase = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot1.child("longitude").getValue());
                       Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase);

                       //String latitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                       //Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                       //String longitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
                       //Log.i("testing for longitude", longitudefromDatabase;

                      //String latitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
                       //Log.i("testing for latitude", latitudefromDatabase);
                      //String longitudefromDatabase = dataSnapshot1.child("longitude").getValue(String.class);
                       //Log.i("testing for longitude", latitudefromDatabase);

                       Double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudefromDatabase);
                       Double Longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudefromDatabase);

                      Intent intent = new Intent(Latitude_Longitude.this, MapsActivity.class);

                      intent.putExtra("latitude", Latitude);
                      intent.putExtra("longitude", Longitude);

                       startActivity(intent);

                   }
               }else {
                    enterTracking.setError("Invalid Tracking ID from database");
                    enterTracking.requestFocus();
                   }
                }
```

Now, the error shows that the input string value was null as shown in the diagram below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWJtP.png)

So, now how should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code:

1. You say `orderByChild("ID")` which means Firebase looks for an `ID` property directly under each direct child node of `/HostID/$uid`. But the `ID` property is actually under `TrackingID/ID`, so that's what you should order/filter on.
2. You're passing a string value in `equalTo(userTrackingID`. But the `ID` values in your database are stored as numeric values, so you should pass a numeric value in the query too.

Combined that means this should be better:

```
String userTrackingID = enterTracking.getText().toString().trim();
Long userTrackingIDNumber =  Long.parseLong(userTrackingID)

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HostID").child(firebaseAuth.getUid());

Query query = reference.orderByChild("TrackingID/ID").equalTo(userTrackingIDNumber);
```

Comment: I have making the changes according to your coding, the program still cannot retrieve data and the logcat keep showing "W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "TrackingID/ID"' at HostID/q6jJMcxtTxMkxiktl6K4eDBSrRP2 to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance" while the log of "checking, this is value message" still not showing out. The program toast the message "Invalid Tracking ID from database" when the tracking ID is entered to the program...

Comment: And there is a point on the message on the logcat 
"W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding '".indexOn": "TrackingID/ID"' at HostID/q6jJMcxtTxMkxiktl6K4eDBSrRP2 to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance"
Why the HostID is q6jJMcxtTxMkxiktl6K4eDBSrRP2? This UID suppose is the UserID but not the HostID. So is the firebase take the wrong path for it?

Comment: Now, I have made the changes as shown above. However, there show an error for the input value as the input string is null. Why this occurs and how should I solve it?

Comment: That sounds like a new problem, so I'd recommend posting a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).